# symfony process Unterminated quoted string

Tags: php, symfony, process, console, doctrine

I have a problem.

I use doctrine.

There is a 'php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Album\Entity" --force  --from-database annotation ./' for console in doctrine.

I want to use with component 'SYMFONY PROCESS' this command...

```
$nameSpace='src\\app\\mobi\\v1\\model\doctrine\\';
    $process = new Process('php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --namespace="'.$nameSpace.'" --force  --from-database annotation ./');
    $process->run();

    // executes after the command finishes
    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }

    echo $process->getOutput();
```

## but.. error : Error Output:

sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

---

what is problem? how to solve?

Comment: Are you working in Unix or Windows platform?